# EF code first model not in sync with database

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

My EF Code First model for some reason is not in sync with the db. I'm getting this error:

```
{"Invalid column name 'Type_Id1'."}
```

The field is actually called 'Type_Id' so I'm not sure from where that 1 comes up. I have the table column called as Type_Id and also I've added a Type_Id in my type entity model.

Why might I be getting that error message, plus why I'm getting 1 at the end of the name?

### Update

My Task class:

```
public class Task
    {
        public Task()
        {
            Language = 1;
            Grades = new HashSet<Grade>();
            Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
            Subjects = new HashSet<Subject>();
            Rooms = new Collection<Room>();
            Tools = new Collection<Tool>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual TaskType Type { get; set; }

        public string Rules { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(200), MinLength(1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int PreperationTime { get; set; }

        public int InstructionTime { get; set; }

        public int TaskTime { get; set; }

        public int Type_Id { get; set; }

        public string VideoLink { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Language { get; set; }

        public int? MinimumParticipants { get; set; }

        public int? MaximumParticipants { get; set; }

        public int? Rating { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Grade> Grades { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tool> Tools { get; set; }
    }
```

DBContext class:

```
public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", false)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TaskType> TaskTypes { get; set; }


        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
```

Comment: will you add some code for you model?

Comment: @Bazinga - there is no real model, the classes hold the properties as in the db structure, and I have dbcontext class with dbsets of all the classes. Please let me know if you need anything specific. Thx for help

Comment: post the code for your POCO classes at least, and your modelbuilder in the DbContext.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro updated

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the FK attribute on your navigation property. EF is creating Type_Id1 because Type_Id already exists (although it can't tell by convention it is the FK).

```
[ForeignKey("Type_Id")] 
public virtual TaskType Type { get; set; }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Relationships

Comment: It is actually FK. Should I remove the public int Type_Id { get; set; } I have currently? Thanks

Comment: No, you leave that in there and then tell EF that is your FK so it doesn't create Type_Id1